# office excel addin reloads/hangs/not responcive when there is more around 5000 data points to print using range value

Tags: office-js

i am developing office addin using officejs. i am using the range value property to show the value on excel as shown in example here https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/range.md#property-access-examples

some detail about my code. 
i have an ajax call which gives me at one point only 5000 data points and i convert that into a format required for `range.values` property and assigned to it and then call context sync, i noticed that my addins hangs or show reload addin on excel client on desktop machine, it works fine in chrome, **how to best handle this case when there is more data point to write. after one ajax call end i will have another call which will also give 5000 points**

my typescript code look like this.

```
public addData(rangeAddress: string, header: any[][], rows: any[][]): JQueryPromise<string> {
            let me = this;
            let defer = $.Deferred();

            Excel.run(function (ctx: Excel.RequestContext) {
                let addressParts = rangeAddress.split("!");
                let oldRange: Excel.Range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(addressParts[0]).getRange(rangeAddress);
                oldRange.unmerge();
                oldRange.format.autofitColumns();
                oldRange.format.autofitRows();
                oldRange.clear();

                return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                    let startCell: Excel.Range = oldRange.getCell(0, 0), headerBoundingRange: Excel.Range, dataRangeStartCell: Excel.Range,
                        completeDataBoundingRange: Excel.Range, headerLength = 0, dataRangeEndCell: Excel.Range;

                    if (header.length > 0 && header[0].length > 0) {
                        headerLength = header[0].length;
                        let headerEndCell = startCell.getOffsetRange(0, header[0].length - 1);
                        headerBoundingRange = startCell.getBoundingRect(headerEndCell);
                        dataRangeStartCell = startCell.getOffsetRange(1, 0);
                        headerBoundingRange.load(["address", "columnCount"]);
                        completeDataBoundingRange = headerBoundingRange;

                    } else {
                        dataRangeStartCell = startCell;
                        completeDataBoundingRange = startCell;
                    }

                    dataRangeEndCell = dataRangeStartCell.getOffsetRange(rows.length > 0 ? rows.length - 1 : 0,
                        rows.length > 0 ? rows[0].length - 1 : 0);

                    let dataBoundingRange = dataRangeStartCell.getBoundingRect(dataRangeEndCell);
                    dataBoundingRange.load(["address", "rowCount", "columnCount"]);
                    completeDataBoundingRange = completeDataBoundingRange.getBoundingRect(dataBoundingRange);
                    completeDataBoundingRange.load("address");
                    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                        dataBoundingRange.values = rows;

                        if (headerLength > 0) {
                            headerBoundingRange.values = [header[0]];
                        }

                        me.formatTable(headerBoundingRange, dataBoundingRange, header.length === 2 ? header[1] : [],
                            Utility.tagDataTableName);

                        defer.resolve(completeDataBoundingRange.address);
                    });
                });
            }).catch(function (error: any) {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
                if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
                }
                defer.reject();
            });

            return defer.promise();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful information on performance, limits and optimization here: [Resource limits and performance optimization for Office Add-ins](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization) (specially on section **Design and implementation techniques**). This shall help you solving the issue.

Also, it is worth to mention that on Windows, Office Add-ins will use Internet Explorer components for loading and hosting the add-in, and so, for a more specific test and comparison, it would be interesting to test the add-in using Office Online on Internet Explorer, rather than Chrome.

Also, if you're using Windows 10, you may find it helpful to debug your add-in on office desktop, as explained on [Debug add-ins using F12 developer tools on Windows 10](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10).